# Swift POST Request (Base64 Image) to PHP Script

Tags: php, ios, swift, post

After reading through numerous similar questions I still don't understand what the problem is here.

I'm trying to send a Base64 encoded image to a simple PHP script, here's my Swift code:

```
func sendImage(encodedImage: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.site.whatever/image_upload.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let postString = "encoded_image=\(encodedImage)"
    let postData = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            // Handle error
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(responseString)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Simple PHP Script

```
$request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

switch ($request_method) {
    case 'POST':
        if (isset($_POST["encoded_image"])) {
            // POST parameter has been set successfully
            $return = ["POSTSET?" => "Yes"];
            echo json_encode($return);
        }
    // POST parameter was not set
    $return = ["POSTSET" => "No"];
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

**Problem:**

With

```
let postString = "encoded_image=\(encodedImage)"
```

*Where encodedImage is set with:*

```
let encodedImage = image.pngData()!.base64EncodedString()
```

it returns `{"POSTSET?","No"}` // POST was not sent

With

```
let postString = "encoded_image=some_random_string"
```

it returns `{"POSTSET?","Yes"}` // POST sent successfully

---

I don't know why it works perfectly until I try and send a Base64.

**Thoughts:**

> Is `request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` the correct content type?
>
> Should I be setting a content length since the Base64 string is so long?
>
> Should `request.httpBody` be encoded using something other than `String.Encoding.utf8`?
>
> Should my PHP be expecting something different to what Swift is sending?

Any insight would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Your Swift code has some other problem (values sent with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` needs to be URL-encoded), but I'm not sure that may cause `{"POSTSET?","No"}`. Is your PHP server configured to receive enough size of POST data? How much is the `post_max_size` of your php.ini?

Comment: Regarding the `post_max_size` variable - when I submit the data using a standard `<form action=“POST”>` it works perfectly, which would suggest the page can handle the long string length, right?

Comment: No. Unless you submit exactly the same base64 string made from your image. Your info would change the priorities of things to be checked. But not sure.

Comment: I’ll check the max post size in case that’s the problem, thanks @OOPer

Comment: That's one possibility I can think of now. If you have some difficulty to check it directly, you can test your `sendImage(encodedImage:)` with some random String, and increase the length by x2 (or more) each step until your PHP server cannot receive it or the size exceeds the base64 String of the image. `let encodedImage = String(repeating: "A", count: n)` may be enough to check if some sort of size limit is causing your issue or not.

Comment: Replace `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` with `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"` in the HTTP Header field.

Comment: I tested the script by sending it gradually increasing string lengths all the way up to 700k characters. So it seems like the server can easily handle a Base64 image.

Comment: And thanks Pranav for the advice, but that did nothing

Comment: Base64 encoded strings often include = signs. This may cause a problem if you are sending the data as form data, which consists of name/value pairs. Try sending a short dummy string that ends with a couple = signs and see what happens.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the advice. I tested a random string with a few equals signs and it went through successfully.. still pondering this one unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string length I was seeing for a Base64 encoded PNG was around 12 million characters on average. The server on which the PHP script is running isn't capable of accepting the request and would result in an error.

I sent a JPG to the API instead, the Base64 string is closer to 3 million when sent like this.

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!
let encodedImage = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

This successfully sends the image, allowing me to decode and save on the back end.